# How to find lower bounds of a modified mixing time (defined below) with respect to spectral of a finite Markov chain?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I am focused on a time-homogeneous continuous-time Markov chain with a finite state space $\mathcal{X}$, whose Markov kernel is $K$ and the corresponding semigroup is $H_t=e^{-t(I-K)}$. The invariant measure is given by $\boldsymbol{\pi}$.

Mixing time $\tau_p$ of the Markov chain with respect to the $L_p$ norm $||f||_p\equiv [\sum_x  \vert f(x)\vert ^p \pi(x)]^{1/p}$ is usually defined as
$\tau_p=\min \{t>0:\max_x ||\frac{\delta_xH_t}{\boldsymbol{\pi}}-1||_p\leq\frac{1}{e} \}$, where $\delta_x(y)=1$ if $y=x$ and $\delta_x(y)=0$ otherwise.

There are many known bound of the above mixing time using the spectral gap or the Logarithmic-Sobolev constant. For example, $\frac{1}{\lambda}\leq \tau_p \leq \frac{2+\log (1/\pi_{\star})}{2\lambda}, $ and $\frac{1}{2\alpha}\leq \tau_p \leq \frac{1}{4\alpha}(4+\log\log(1/\pi _{\star}))$ when $1\leq p \leq 2$. Here, $\lambda$ is the spectral gap and $\alpha$ is the Logarithmic-Sobolev constant (Logarithmic-Sobolev inequalities for finite Markov chains, *The Annals of Applied Probability*
1996, Vol. 6, No. 3, 695] 750).

**My question is**, if we replace the delta function $\delta_x(y)$ in the original definition of the mixing time with **a general probability measure $\mu$** (and cancel the maximization procedure) to gain a modified mixing time $\tau^{\prime}$, can we still find a lower bound for it using $\lambda$ or $\alpha$? That is,
$\tau_p^{\prime}=\min \{t>0:||\frac{\mu H_t}{\boldsymbol{\pi}}-1||_p\leq\frac{1}{e} \}$.

Since there are lower bound for the mixing time, I guess the answer is positve. **Intuitively, the $\tau^{\prime}$ should be of the order of $\frac{D[\boldsymbol{\mu}||\boldsymbol{\pi}]}{\lambda}$ or $\frac{D_{KL}[\boldsymbol{\mu}||\boldsymbol{\pi}]}{\alpha}$,** where $D[\cdot||\cdot]$ is some distance function, like Kullback-Leibler divergence (relative entropy) $D_{KL}[\cdot||\cdot]$. That is, the modified mixing time is proportional to the initial distance from the stationary distribution (invariant measure), which is rational. To prove the intuition, I need to find the lower bound and upper bound of the modified mixing time.

By the way, the question is physically motivated, because the modified mixing time is actually very close to the relaxation time in physics literature, in which the dynamics generally starting from arbitrary initial distribution instead of a give state. In a very recent paper [[PHYSICAL REVIEW LETTERS 130, 230404 (2023)]](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.130.230404), the authors proved that the relaxation time is upper bounded as $\tau\leq \frac{S_2(\mu||\pi)}{\lambda}$, which is in support of my intuition. (In particular, I would like to know whether similar upper bound and lower bound related to the Logarithmic-Sobolev constant $\alpha$ exist.)